# Base64 image taking too much time to upload to server

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on **cordova android app**. In which I have to capture image through **cordova capture plugin** and upload it to server.  I am facing a problem in that when uploading high quality image then it is taking too much time. How can I resolve this issue?

**this is client side controller.**

```
navigator.camera.getPicture($scope.onPhotoDataGlrySuccess, $scope.onGlryFail, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            targetWidth: 200,

        });

$scope.onPhotoDataGlrySuccess = function(imageData) {
        //var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        $scope.imgsrc = imageData;
        $scope.imgname = Date.now();
        $scope.dataObj = {
            img: $scope.imgsrc,
            id: $scope.userid
        }
        dbServices.addImageToUserProfile($scope.dataObj).then(function(response) {
            //$scope.img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data[0].user_image;
            if(response.data[0].user_image){
                $scope.img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data[0].user_image;
            }
        })
    }
```

**this is client service**

```
this.addImageToUserProfile = function (data) {

    return $http.post('/addimagetoProfile', {
        img : data.img,
        id : data.id
    }).then(function(response){
        return response;
    })
}
```

**this is server controller**

```
    app.post('/addimagetoProfile', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('UPDATE user SET user_image="' + req.body.img + '" WHERE id= ' + req.body.id + '', function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            //res.json(rows);
            connection.query('select id,name,city,expertise,user_image from user where id = ' + req.body.id + '', function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (!err) {
                    res.json(rows);
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            })
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }

    })
})
```

Even after setting quality to 50 (in capture controller) it is taking too much time. **How can I minimize the upload time** so that I can upload image with better quality by increasing it to around 80.

Is changing **base64** to image file and then uploading to server using **angular-file-upload** can resolve this? If so then how we can convert **base64** to image file.

Comment: Please explain better: the problem is the long request or the base64->image conversion in android?

Comment: high quality image are taking much time to send to server hence i want to convert base64 we get after camera capture in cordova to image file and upload it to server using ng-file-upload. 
the main prob is how to convert base64 to image file on client side?

Comment: Converting your image to base64 doesn't change the upload time. If your upload is slow, is because the image is too big: isn't better to resize the image before upload?

Comment: can you tell me how to do that.

Comment: Please edit your question before: ask for a solution, explaining exactly what is your problem (the upload time). It's not a discussion between you and I but other people could be interested in this topic. Thank you.

Comment: post it as string with your request parameter and at server side decode and store it

Comment: yeah that's what i am doing but it is taking too much time. i am updating question with code

Comment: @ashish_pbh: convert base64 string to byte array `byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64Content, Base64.DEFAULT);`

Comment: Can you explain little bit more. how it will minimize time.

Comment: @ashish_pbh: my previous comment just for your question `how we can convert base64 to image file`

Comment: ok thankyou..going to apply this.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this feature in following way. **Actually sending base-64 encoded image string is always faster** than uploading file to server. I recommend you to use base-64 encoding.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20,correctOrientation : true,targetWidth: 700,
      targetHeight: 700,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
     }); 

        function onSuccess(imageData) {
            myImage = imageData; // variable my image will contain base-64 encoded image

        }
```

quality, target width and height parameters are optional you can change them to satisfy your requirements

Comment: but my image is coming blurry in quality 50 then how come yours is working fine in 20?

Comment: then you please remove image quality option and try uploading and share results

Comment: yeah that's what i was doing..even i described the whole code above but the problem is , here it is taking too much time but yours working fast. can you compare your method with above written mine's and tell me if there any difference in both ?? May be that is cousing the delay at my side.

Comment: Thanks Sunil, Removed quality in option and worked like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you do not need that much high resolution, so lower the resolution of the photo and then send it to the server. But if you want to keep the size, another option is to send it in multiple parts and show a progress bar to the user.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31238500)